# Micro Front Ends with React Redux Hooks and saga

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga, micro-frontend

I am trying to find out sources for migrating my application to micro front ends and I am unable to find any proper document for converting a react redux hooks application to micro front ends. If anybody implemented please give the reference of these docs. Thank u!!

Comment: Maybe Piral helps you here. https://github.com/smapiot/piral

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy would be to transform your backend into a restfull webservice, or webservices if you already work with micro-services.

With that done, take a look at this lib:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin

It is a micro-application ready to communicate with a restfull backend, you can create such an application for each rule you want to separate!